# c# Finding similar values in the database

Tags: c#, database

I created an access database and connected to C# code. In the database, I have 2 columns (ip and port). My question is how to find the same IP that connects to different value of port column. With other words, I want to search if the same IP connects to many different ports. Any idea?!!

Thank you

Comment: are you looking for a `group by ip`

Comment: Show us your code and explain which part of code causing the problem.

Comment: I want to know if I have one IP in my database repeated with many different port numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ip FROM tablename GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(distinct port) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ip FROM tableName GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(distinct port) > 1;`